# Tag "input" ambígua e utilizada incorretamente

Tags: debate, tags, wikis-de-tags

A tag [input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input) atualmente existente parece-me estar a ser utilizada de forma incorreta.

*Input* é comummente utilizado para referir a introdução de dados numa aplicação, o ato de um utilizador facultar dados para uma aplicação.

Mas o que tenho [observado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input) é o seu uso para nos referirmos à tag de HTML `<input/>`.

Se não já, num futuro próximo, vai começar a surgir uma certa confusão entre o ato de *input* e a tag `<input/>`.

Seria bom criar uma tag `html-input` e *retagar* as perguntas existentes, bem como atualizar a informação da atual tag [input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input) para indicar o seu correto uso e desambiguar esta questão ?

Vejo este problema resolvido de forma eficiente no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/input/info).

Comment: Acho que a solução e mesmo essa.